# Mvc.net date field changing to default date

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in cshtml :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfBirth, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "mm/dd/yyyy", id = "datepicker", @data_masked_input = "99/99/9999" })
```

Here DateOfBirth is a datetime property.

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }`
```

The controller code is such :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(Employee emp, string returnUrl)
{
    .....
}
```

Employee class contains the DateOfBirth which is also DateTime. For some reason I am getting the value for DOB property as the default date i.e., '01/01/0001'. 
This happens only for specific dates like if the day is '19'. For e.g. if we enter '11/19/1984' in the property field we get DOB as the default date.

Is something wrong with my code?

Comment: Looks like a culture issue. What is the culture on the server - is it one that expects dates in `MM/dd/yyyy` format?

Comment: I think the server expects it in 'MM/dd/yyyy' format. How should it be a culture issue?

Comment: Well your profile say you are from India, so unless you have specifically set the culture to (say) `en-US` in the web.config` file then you server will expect dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format

Comment: You are getting default date probably because if you enter '11/19/1984' and the format is dd/MM/yyyy, there is no 19. month and the code returns default date instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically a culture issue. For that you need to write a logic in the global.asax.cs file as below.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
        //ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new DateTimeModelBinder());
    }
```

This logic is used to set culture info.
This same issue will face while posting date in dd/MM/yyyy format. For that please write logic as below in global.asax.cs file in "Appication_Start" section as below.

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new DateTimeModelBinder());
```

and create DateTimeModelBinder.cs file as below logic

```
public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var holderType = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ContainerType;
        if (bindingContext.ModelMetadata.PropertyName != null)
        {
            var property = holderType.GetProperty(bindingContext.ModelMetadata.PropertyName);
            var displayFormat = string.Empty;
            displayFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";

            var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayFormat) && value != null)
            {
                DateTime date;
                displayFormat = displayFormat.Replace("{0:", string.Empty).Replace("}", string.Empty);
                // use the format specified in the DisplayFormat attribute to parse the date
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value.AttemptedValue, displayFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
                {
                    return date;
                }
                else
                {
                    bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(
                        bindingContext.ModelName,
                        string.Format("{0} is an invalid date format", value.AttemptedValue)
                    );
                }
            }
        }


        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
```

Please test it.

Comment: This code has worked. Thank you so much. Only change I made for the Application_BeginRequest is the date format. I did not add the model binder class as of now, since I want the format to be same.
`protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
            newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
            newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
        }`

Comment: I hope I am not misinterpreting the use of the BindModel method here.

Comment: All OP need to do is set the culture in the `web.config` file